# Bearer token and key in a request to an API

Tags: python, api, request

How can I use environment variables inside this header? I already created my environment variable called 'API_TOKEN' and also 'API_KEY'. And I would like to replace in these fields:

```
api_token = os.environ['API_TOKEN']
api_key = os.environ['API_KEY']

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "MYKEY": "MY KEY VALUE HERE",
    "MYTOKEN": "MY TOKEN VALUE HERE"
}
```

I already tried doing f"Bearer " + api_key or f"Bearer " + api_token. Also putting the variables inside {{}} without the Bearer and it still isn't working. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Can I only use bearer if it is to pass values ​​from a token or can I also use it to pass values ​​from a key?

Comment: You should be able to just use the variables in the dictionary: `"MYKEY": api_key`, etc.

Comment: @Mark 
I tried that way too and I didn't succeed either.

Comment: I was looking deeper into the documentation of the api and found that it uses the  Open API 3.0 (OAS 3.0) . It wouldn't be with bearer but api_key